# Background task on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I plan to create a business app that runs on iOS and communicates with a webservice. The app is meant to be an online app, but when there is no internet connection, the user should still be able to register a notification locally and the app should send the notification *automatically* (without further user intervention) as soon as there is an internet connection again. This should also work when the user closes the app while he has no internet connection.

Is it possible to do this on iOS? (I know it works on Android with a service)

Does this need a special permission ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [developer guide section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html), specifically the part about local notifications in iOS and Android.

Notice that services can work in native code but the local notifications are portable.